# Hazelcast refuses Member

Tags: java, hazelcast, distributed-caching

In our system, we have a Hazelcast cluster consisting of 2 nodes.
Hazelcast is refusing the connection of the other member. **What could be the reasons?**

In the log file i see:

```
2017-10-13 17:39:25,419 [T:B_Hazelcast.IO.thread-Acceptor, C:] INFO  c.h.n.tcp.SocketAcceptorThread | [10.15.162.50]:5701 [ESB_Hazelcast] [3.7.2] **Accepting socket connection** from /10.15.162.51:33497

2017-10-13 17:39:25,420 [T:_ESB_Hazelcast.cached.thread-5, C:] INFO  c.h.n.t.TcpIpConnectionManager | [10.15.162.50]:5701 [ESB_Hazelcast] [3.7.2] **Established socket connection** between /10.15.162.50:5701 and /10.15.162.51:33497

2017-10-13 17:39:25,428 [T:ity-generic-operation.thread-0, C:] INFO  c.h.c.i.p.t.AuthenticationMessageTask | [10.15.162.50]:5701 [ESB_Hazelcast] [3.7.2] Received auth from Connection[id=12, /10.15.162.50:5701->/10.15.162.51:33497, endpoint=null, alive=true, type=JAVA_CLIENT], **successfully authenticated**, principal : ClientPrincipal{uuid='39851f2a-cc6e-4bbb-be33-603352b2aaa6', ownerUuid='126694e3-daee-4999-8afc-870f1cd9da2e'}, owner connection : true

2017-10-13 17:39:25,512 [T:ity-generic-operation.thread-0, C:] WARN
c.h.c.i.o.ClientReAuthOperation | [10.15.162.50]:5701 [ESB_Hazelcast] [3.7.2] com.hazelcast.spi.exception.**CallerNotMemberException: Not Member!** this: [10.15.162.50]:5701, caller: [10.15.162.51]:5701, partitionId: -1, operation: com.hazelcast.client.impl.operations.ClientReAuthOperation, service: hz:core:clientEngine
```

The server is instantiated with

```
public static HazelcastInstance createServer(Environment env) {
    com.hazelcast.config.Config hazelcastConfig = new com.hazelcast.config.Config();
    final String clusterName = env.getProperty("core.hazelcast.clusterName");
    hazelcastConfig.getGroupConfig().setName(clusterName);
    hazelcastConfig.getGroupConfig().setPassword(env.getProperty("core.hazelcast.clusterPassword"));

    JoinConfig joinConfig = hazelcastConfig.getNetworkConfig().getJoin();
    joinConfig.getMulticastConfig().setEnabled(false);
    joinConfig.getTcpIpConfig().setEnabled(true);
    final String members = env.getProperty("core.hazelcast.members");

    //Here it comes!!!
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(members)) {
        joinConfig.getTcpIpConfig().addMember(members);
    }
    hazelcastConfig.setProperty(GroupProperty.LOGGING_TYPE.getName(), "slf4j");
    return new HazelcastLifecycleBean(Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hazelcastConfig));
}
```

In the configuration file is

```
core.hazelcast.members=10.15.162.50,10.15.162.51
```

And this is passed to `joinConfig.getTcpIpConfig().addMember`

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a fuller example ? Your class is defined as `static HazelcastInstance createServer` but the returned object is `new HazelcastLifecycleBean` which is incompatible. Also, the suggestion from the error message is that one of the machines is a _type=JAVA_CLIENT_ not a sevrer

Comment: Is the other process a client ? Posting the logs would help

Comment: Hi @NeilStevenson, good question. Now, i'm confused about the last log message. Why would a ClientReAuthOperation complain about not being a **member**? On both addresses x.x.x.50  and x.x.x.51 are my members, but also clients. But port 5701 is the server port.

Comment: Can you try without the clients ?

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the port as part of your tcp member addresses. Instead of core.hazelcast.members=10.15.162.50,10.15.162.51 use core.hazelcast.members=10.15.162.50:5701,10.15.162.51:5701